# Java: class resolved?

Tags: java, class, compilation, declaration

I hope this question is not repeated.  But just can't find answer anywhere:

I have ONE folder containing two files one A.java another B.class.

Now in A.java I am trying to declare

```
public class A extends Applet{
...
    B aB;
}
```

The compiler gives me:

```
B cannot be resolved to a type
```

I read a lot of posts that say if the files are in the same folder, I don't need to import. Could anyone help me to "resolve" this problem?
Thanks much appreciated!

-----------SOLVED! - SEE ANSWER BELOW------------------

Comment: in file a.java you have class 'A', I think in file b.class (in b.java) the Class name would have been 'B', are you sure it is small 'b' ? please check!! If problem not solved try posting code of class B.

Comment: changed... yes they are consistent.  I am using A and B as two examples - the original codes are a little bit complicated... But maybe I have to post them soon.

Comment: Could you show full folder structure with names and packaging in class declarations?

Answer (score 1):

The .class files need to reside in a directory referenced by the classpath variable. Usually you put your .java files in one directory (src), compile to another directory (bin) and have external .class files in a third directory (lib). The commands will look like this:

```
# compile
javac -sourcepath src -classpath lib -d bin
# run
java -classpath bin:lib A
```

Using an IDE like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) should help a lot here as it takes care of most of the details

Comment: Thanks! It works, I used "javac -classpath dirForAandB A.java" much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The simple case that you've posted works for me. I'd check the following things:

- Are you sure that `B.class` is present in the same folder as `A.java`?
- Are you running `javac` from that folder?
- Have you typed the class name `B` correctly everywhere in your program? This includes capitalization, as Java identifiers are case sensitive.
- Are there any `package` declarations in your program? If there are, none of this is going to work, since you're implicitly using the default package by just throwing everything into a folder.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler looks for *.class file in its class path.  It will only look for *.java files in the same source directories.  You need to set the class path to include the directory.

Or you could use an IDE which sets all this up for you and saves a lot time in the process.

Comment: If you're just using the default package, the compiler will find `.class` files in the current directory.